# ruby-rubocop cannot load such file -- rubocop/rspec/focused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rubocop, rubocop-rspec

I've installed ruby-rubocop for VSCode, and gem installed rubocop, but every time I save a file, this error is thrown:

```
    cannot load such file -- rubocop/rspec/focused
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-0.85.0/lib/rubocop/config_loader_resolver.rb:15:in `block in resolve_requires'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-0.85.0/lib/rubocop/config_loader_resolver.rb:11:in `each'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-0.85.0/lib/rubocop/config_loader_resolver.rb:11:in `resolve_requires'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-0.85.0/lib/rubocop/config_loader.rb:45:in `load_file'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-0.85.0/lib/rubocop/config_loader.rb:90:in `configuration_from_file'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-0.85.0/lib/rubocop/config_store.rb:54:in `for_dir'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-0.85.0/lib/rubocop/config_store.rb:44:in `for'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-0.85.0/lib/rubocop/target_finder.rb:180:in `block in process_explicit_path'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-0.85.0/lib/rubocop/target_finder.rb:179:in `reject'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-0.85.0/lib/rubocop/target_finder.rb:179:in `process_explicit_path'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-0.85.0/lib/rubocop/target_finder.rb:39:in `block in find'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-0.85.0/lib/rubocop/target_finder.rb:35:in `each'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-0.85.0/lib/rubocop/target_finder.rb:35:in `find'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-0.85.0/lib/rubocop/runner.rb:69:in `find_target_files'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-0.85.0/lib/rubocop/runner.rb:34:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-0.85.0/lib/rubocop/cli/command/execute_runner.rb:21:in `execute_runner'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-0.85.0/lib/rubocop/cli/command/execute_runner.rb:13:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-0.85.0/lib/rubocop/cli/command.rb:10:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-0.85.0/lib/rubocop/cli/environment.rb:17:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-0.85.0/lib/rubocop/cli.rb:65:in `run_command'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-0.85.0/lib/rubocop/cli.rb:72:in `execute_runners'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-0.85.0/lib/rubocop/cli.rb:41:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-0.85.0/exe/rubocop:13:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

Please help! I've been trying to make this work, and scouring the internet for solutions, but haven't had any luck yet.

Answer (score 3):

That cop is part of the [rubocop-rspec](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop-rspec) plug-in, so you may also have to run `gem install rubocop-rspec`.

Comment: I've installed rubocop-rspe, restarted, but still got the same error.

Comment: Any plugin should be explicitly enabled in the .rubocop.yml file. rubocop-rspec-focused gem is not maintained anymore so it makes sense to switch to the official rubocop-rspec

Answer (score 0):

Found and fixed the issue.

As it turns out, the culprits are:

1. rubocop -v 0.85.0
2. rubocop-rspec

The fix was just to downgrade both since our organization is using the older versions. So now I installed:

1. rubocop -v 0.75.1
2. rubocop-rspec-focused

Comment: https://github.com/lovewithfood/rubocop-rspec-focused has been archived and is not maintained anymore.